# Divide a string (as a date) to get a particular part of the string (as a month)

Tags: iphone, string, date, components, nsdate

I'm getting some data from a webserver. Within this data there is a date (i.e. 11-07-1978). I'd like to get the month as an integer like (int month = 7).

I have tried to make an NSDate from the String and get the month as a component with NSDateComponents. However I'm only getting the value 1.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
        NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"result_expdate"]];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:dateFromString];
        int day = [components day];    
        int month = [components month];
        int year = [components year];

NSLog(@"month = %d", month);
```

How can I get the month as an integer?

Comment: Your date formats don't match between exposition and code — is that a typo or is it possibly the actual problem?

Comment: You say that the formatted date is part of a larger string.  What are you doing to separate out the date portion from the surrounding content, and which variable(s) in your code correspond to the date portion and/or the whole string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way of doing it-
this is hand typed so there may be typo's...

```
//chop up the string by "-"
NSString * dateString = @"11-07-2011";
NSArray * tempArray = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

// set string to month
NSString * monthString = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:1]description];

//remove 0's from date if any
monthString = [monthString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@""];

//change string to int
int month = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",monthString] intValue];
```